# API que retorna o valor de uma ação nos últimos dias em JSON

Tags: node.js, api, react-native, expo

Estou fazendo um projeto ligado ao mercado financeiro em react-native e até o momento só achei APIS que me retornam o valor atual de uma ação. Preciso de uma que me retorne os valores que essa ação teve nos últimos dias, para poder formar um gráfico do desempenho dessa ação no período de tempo em questão por exemplo nos últimos 30 dias, 7 dias ou até mesmo nas últimas 24 horas, alguém sabe se existe ou se tem alguma forma de conseguir esses dados?

segue um exemplo do retorno que eu busco, nesse caso é o que está no sparkline em sparkline_in_7d

```
{
    "id": "bitcoin",
    "symbol": "btc",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
    "current_price": 103555,
    "market_cap": 1983533638163,
    "market_cap_rank": 1,
    "fully_diluted_valuation": 2174651883386,
    "total_volume": 140590535096,
    "high_24h": 105786,
    "low_24h": 103196,
    "price_change_24h": -1955.1757915963099,
    "price_change_percentage_24h": -1.85307,
    "market_cap_change_24h": -37346657215.05859,
    "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": -1.84804,
    "circulating_supply": 19154425,
    "total_supply": 21000000,
    "max_supply": 21000000,
    "ath": 380542,
    "ath_change_percentage": -72.74555,
    "ath_date": "2021-11-09T04:09:45.771Z",
    "atl": 149.66,
    "atl_change_percentage": 69200.85187,
    "atl_date": "2013-07-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "roi": null,
    "last_updated": "2022-09-18T21:09:58.070Z",
    "sparkline_in_7d": {
      "price": [
        21774.051156897473,
        21598.342717899886,
        21606.183946624507,
        21577.7168121273,
        21625.30916872812,
        21666.046561382085,
        21741.569832995458,
        21686.930126120267,
        22202.035748239385,
        21770.96642915996,
        21594.133225623027,
        21747.326261531707,
        21781.115331711822,
        21804.567465543205,
        22117.52421447349,
        22242.652543728345,
        22195.691184367177,
```

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta e ela foi fechada. Para ter a postagem aberta, edite [sua postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/564940/70) conforme orientação do quadro de fechamento. Se a edição atender aos objetivos do site, a comunidade reabre a postagem via voto. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o campo de comentários desta foi bloqueado, mas você ou outros membros da comunidade podem usar o espaço da postagem original.